# Remote access MySql via remote phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

I have a phpMyAdmin with MySQL on a linux remote machine to which I can connect with no problem with a browser.

But when I am trying to connect a DB in MySQL from a .NET program in my machine, I am getting an error message:

```
Authentication to host 'theIpNumber' for user 'newUserName' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'newUserName'@'myMachineName' (using password: YES)
```

I tried to configured it like it is explained here: http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-mysql-or-phpmyadmin-from-outside
creating a new user with password in phpMyAdmin and changing the config.inc.php

Then in my app.config I have the connection string with:

```
connectionString="server=theIpNumber;UserId=newUserName;Password=newUserPassword;database=theDB"
```

But I am still getting the same error message when I run my program. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it adding in phpMyAdmin another user with the same name "newUserName" and password, and with the host value "%"